# Svelte fly transition between 2 paragraphs

Tags: tailwind-css, svelte

I am trying to make transition between 2 sentences in svelte using `fly` from `'svelte/transition'` and i completely stuck at trying to not break other ui. Also, i use tailwindcss because i'm not a frontend developer and have hard time to memorize every possible css property.

I have tried 2 solutions:

- using flex
- using position: absolute

*Only difference is in #key->span->class*

At first one everything "jumping" across the screen, making it look junky. Code:

```
<script lang="ts">
    import { fly } from 'svelte/transition';
    let value: string = "";
    let question: string = 'First sentence';
</script>

<div class="container text-center flex items-center justify-center flex-col">
    {#key question}
        <span
            class="text-5xl my-24 "
            in:fly={{ y: 200, duration: 500 }}
            out:fly={{ y: -200, duration: 500 }}>{question}</span
        >
    {/key}
    <form on:submit|preventDefault={() => { question = "Next sentence"; value = ""; }}>
        <button class="text-gray-400 text-sm my-4">
            Press here to move to next sentence</button
        >
    </form>
</div>
```

Second approach gives weird scaling (but looks ok on 80-100% on my pc). Code:

```
<script lang="ts">
    import { fly } from 'svelte/transition';
    let value: string = "";
    let question: string = 'First sentence';
</script>

<div class="container text-center flex items-center justify-center flex-col">
    {#key question}
        <span
            class="text-5xl my-24 "
            in:fly={{ y: 200, duration: 500 }}
            out:fly={{ y: -200, duration: 500 }}>{question}</span
        >
    {/key}
    <form on:submit|preventDefault={() => { question = "Next sentence"; value = ""; }}>
        <button class="text-gray-400 text-sm my-4">
            Press here to move to next sentence</button
        >
    </form>
</div>
```

What i should do to fix one of this problems (If it possible, first preferrably)?

Comment: "have hard time to memorize every possible css property" You just replace that problem with memorizing a class name for every combination of property and value 

Comment: Inline elements don't fly properly.  Only block elements do.  Span elements are inline elements.

Comment: See [this article](https://webjose.hashnode.dev/animated-timer-the-svelte-experience#heading-but-i-said-animated-timer) of an animated timer.  The flying components are span elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put only the changing content in its own container, e.g. a grid with one cell and make sure the transitioning elements are both in said cell, so they do not push stuff around, e.g.:

```html
<div class="grid grid-cols-1 grid-rows-1">
  {#key question}
    <span
      class="text-5xl my-24
             col-start-1 col-span-1
             row-start-1 row-span-1"
      in:fly={{ y: 200, duration: 500 }}
      out:fly={{ y: -200, duration: 500 }}>
      {question}
    </span>
  {/key}
</div>
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/e89fa44e3cd74184a497242ed53f43d0?version=4.2.0)